# Access to SharedPreferences method via class

Tags: flutter, dart

I've a separate file which includes a class with a function:

**getstatus.dart**

```
class GetStatus {
  isActive() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool boolValue = prefs.getBool('notification') ?? false;
    return boolValue;
  }
}
```

To access the function: `final bool getStatus = GetStatus().isActive();`. However Flutter gives me the error `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool'`. Probably the **isActive()** method is wrong but what exactly should I change? Btw: the return value must be a bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the signature to:

```
Future<bool> isActive() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getBool('notification') ?? false;
}
```

To consume this, you need to:

```
fecthActive() async {    
  var activeValue = await getStatusInstance.isActive();
  //do something else...
}
```

Now you can use `activeValue` as a bool.

To deal with Futures in Dart, goto this doc: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: `prefs.getBool` doesn't return you `Future<bool>`, rather `bool`.

Comment: yeah, I get this message: `Error: A value of type 'Future<bool>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'`

Comment: Changing `final bool getStatus...` to `final Future<bool> getStatus...` works. But I need the value in 'bool'. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks dude, but I'm a little bit confused. Where should I put this line of code?

Comment: @Bassam I updated the answer, basically depends of your application, where are you calling this method, you need to use await inside async call or use the 'on complete' methods: then(...) or whenComplete(...), etc